# Flask: token-based authorization

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am building a basic app with Flask: it has a unique route that requests just a **token** authentication, i.e. if the token provided in the headers is correct, then the request is satisfied. To do so, I installed both `Flask` and `Flask-Security`. This is a snippet of my app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.security import auth_token_required
from flask.ext.security import Security

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_KEY'] = 'mytoken'
security = Security(app)

@app.route('/myurl')
@auth_token_required
def myrequest():
    return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I test it by running:

`$ curl -H 'Authorization: Token token="mytoken"' localhost:5000/myurl`

or even:

`$ curl localhost:5000/myurl`

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 113, in decorated
    if _check_token():
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 50, in _check_token
    header_key = _security.token_authentication_header
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_security/decorators.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    _security = LocalProxy(lambda: current_app.extensions['security'])
KeyError: 'security'
```

Do you know where the error lies? Is it in the app or in some conflicts among the Flask libraries?

**EDIT**: added `Security(app)` initialization

Comment: check that it has examples:https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky

Answer (score 1):

```
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
```

security = Security(app, user_datastore)

Comment: Please add description